# Automation of PV and creation of folders in NFS server for Jupyterhub on Kubernetes

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I have used the following GitHub link for jupyterhub installation:https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/jupyterhub

My problem is while user tries to log in jupyterhub it will create PVC for each user from helm side and we need to create PV and NFS folders from our side. Doing this process for each user is not ideal.

Even if we write some scripts to automate this process, I dont how we will trigger the script because when user signs into jupyterhub it should trigger that script then our manual process of creating all this things for each user will be gone.

If anyone have any idea to resolve this, please comment your suggestions.